# Swift Struct with static values

Tags: swift, struct

I use this struct :

```
struct Constants {
  struct array {
     static let fuel = [NSLocalizedString("Gasoline", comment: ""),
                           NSLocalizedString("Diesel", comment: ""),
                           NSLocalizedString("Hybrid", comment: ""),
                           NSLocalizedString("Electric", comment: ""),
                           NSLocalizedString("other", comment: "")]
  }
}
```

I do the call `Constants.array.fuel`  in other place, it's work fine.
the problem is when I change the app language, the `NSLocalizedString` not working as expected (I get the old translate).
probably because I use `static`. in other viewcontrollers, `NSLocalizedString` works fine.
when I remove `static`, I get :

```
Instance member 'fuel' cannot be used on type 'Constants.array'
```

any help please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `fuel` property is a constant. Its initialized only once and then won't change during whole application lifetime.

You may make it calculated property by replacing `static let` with 
`static var fuel: [NSLocalizedString] { return [NSLocalizedString("Gasoline", comment: ""), ...] }`

This way, property will be calculated each time you access it. Of course, it won't work as fast as with constant.

Comment: as you said it won't work as fast as with constant. is there any other way to reset the struct for exemple? otherwise I'll accept your answer. and thank you

Comment: @abdel You can make a private optional property which you set to `nil`. Then make your property a computed property, which if the private property is `nil` sets it to your array and then returns the private property unwrapped. When you change the language, just set the private property to `nil` again to force it to be recalculated on next use.